# Can my java client print out the echo statements from my php server?

Tags: java, php

Could I somehow capture the echos and use them in my java client? I'm trying to obtain a jwt from the server so my client can use it and send a message to the server.

Comment: have you *tried anything* so far? for example a httpClient or something?

Comment: The `echo` is just the output of an HTTP response. So if you use any HTTP client, you can capture this output.

Comment: @AnimatedLime "having a php server" does *not* count in any way as *trying* for what you want to do....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests), where there is an HTTP request and response, so it's possible to capture the answer.

Comment: should be marked as a duplicate then

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: I just searched `Java HTTP Client` :).
Indeed it should be marked as duplicate, I'll flag it.